# Захват возвращаемого типа в typescript

Tags: typescript

хочу провернуть что-то вроде этого:

```
const f = () => 5;
type t = typeof f();
```

однако typescript ругается.

можно конечно сделать так:

```
const f = () => 5;
const r = f();
type t = typeof r;
```

но тогда у меня создается экземпляр, который не используется ни для чего кроме определения типа, и мне это не очень нравится.

можно ли как то захватить возвращаемый тип?

Comment: А что будет если так сделать type t = typeof (f())?

Comment: Сделай баг репорт (на английском) в github на репозитории typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с TypeScript 2.8 нам доступен [ReturnType<>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet), который вполне решает вашу проблему...

```
const f = () => 5;
type t = ReturnType<typeof f>; // number
```

Comment: Петр, спасибо! за столько времени я уже нашел данный функционал, но надеялся что найдется добрый человек, чей ответ я с удовольствием отмечу как правильный)

Comment: Почему бы просто не вернуть `number`? Зачем такие сложные конструкции `ReturnType<typeof f>`? `type t = number`